# Response from AWS lambda function called from another lambda function is always null

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have two lambda functions and I need to call a function named `sendHealthData` from a function named `receiveHealthData`. I'm using Node.JS 8.10 and the [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) framework.

Here's the code to `receiveHealthData`:

```
const env = process.env;
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const Lambda = new aws.Lambda();
const S3 = new aws.S3();

exports.main = (event, context, callback) => {

    const params = {
        FunctionName: "sendHealthData",
        InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
        Payload: JSON.stringify(event)
    }

    Lambda.invoke(params, function(error, remainingHealthData) {

        if (error) {

            reject(error);
        }
        else {

            console.log("Remaining: " + remainingHealthData["Payload"]);

            if (!remainingHealthData["Payload"]) {

                reject(new Error("Payload is null"));
            }  
            else {

                resolve(remainingHealthData);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this is `sendHealthData`:

```
exports.main = async (event, context, callback) => {

    callback(null, "Sent Health Data!");
}
```

`remainingHealthData["Payload"]` is null everytime.

The output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(remainingHealthData))` is:

`{"StatusCode":200,"Payload":'null'}`

When I invoke `sendHealthData` through `serverless invoke --function sendHealthData` I get the expected result: "Sent Health Data!"

I got the expected response only once: when I changed the timeout of the `sendHealthData` function. But the strange thing is that I changed it to a smaller value. It was 10 and I changed it to 6.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using `RequestResponse` as `InvocationType` but your `sendHealthData` AWS Lambda doesn't return a valid JSON (just a string).

A small quote out of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html) says:

> Payload — (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String)
>
> It is the JSON representation of the object returned by the Lambda function. This is present only if the invocation type is RequestResponse.

So as soon as you change the return value of your `sendHealthData` AWS Lambda to the following it should work as you expect:

```
exports.main = async (event, context, callback) => {
  callback(null, {
    "message": "Sent Health Data!"
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to do as you said but I continue to get strange results. For example: right after I deploy the function and run it, I get the correct results. If I try to run it a second time immediately after the first time, the response I get is `0`;